# I want to run a exe file using task scheduler using GPO

Tags: windows, excel, operating-system, server, windows-server-2012

We have windows server 2012 in network,

I have an exe file which is fetching the installed software information from the users computer, and create a excel report.

I decided to run the exe file using group policy task scheduler, at every 3 PM every day. Its executing in client machine at 3 PM

But, excel report is not generated, its giving an error that

"C:\windows\system32\report.xls access denied"

seems report is unable to generate in the path

Any possibility to create a report in different folder without any error

Regards
admin